# What do bulk Fourier modes look like in the boundary theory?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle

Suppose we have a bulk theory that has some holographic CFT dual at the boundary. Suppose we construct an operator that 'looks like' (whatever that needs to mean) a Fourier mode in the bulk perspective. If we consider this as operator purely from the perspective of the boundary theory, what sort of data is this picking up about our CFT?

Comment: That is the subject of https://sites.krieger.jhu.edu/jared-kaplan/files/2016/05/AdSCFTCourseNotesCurrentPublic.pdf

Comment: I think you are asking something along the lines of bulk reconstruction backwards? Is that it?